# xsl get node that not compare in key

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

In this example i have this xml

```
<CityStates>
<States>
    <State Abbr="AL">Alabama</State>
    <State Abbr="AK">Alaska</State>
    <State Abbr="AZ">Arizona</State>
    <State Abbr="AR">Arkansas</State>
</States>
<Cities>
    <City State="NY" >New York</City>
    <City State="CA" >Los Angeles</City>
    <City State="AZ" >Chicago</City>
    <City State="AR" >Houston</City>
    <City State="AR" >Philadelphia</City>   
  </Cities>
</CityStates>
```

I would like to view only the nodes that do not have the State with the Key()
xsl is this:

```
<xsl:key name="keyState" match="State" use="@Abbr"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:for-each select="//City">
                    <xsl:value-of select="City"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a predicate `City[not(key('keyState', @State))]` i.e.

```
        <xsl:for-each select="//City[not(key('keyState', @State))]">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
<xsl:template match="/CityStates">
    <xsl:for-each select="Cities/City[not(key('keyState', @State))]" >
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

You haven't posted the expected result. You will probably want to add some kind of delimiter after the `xsl:value-of` instruction.

Comment: Thank you very much!